# Sum of points of stories in PivotalTracker gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, padrino, pivotaltracker

I have started using the [PivotalTracker](https://github.com/jsmestad/pivotal-tracker) gem in my Ruby on Sinatra-Padrino.

It provides really good API(s), but I am stuck in a requirement. I want `the sum of the points/estimates of all the stories which are features`.

What I tried (project is an instance of the PT project):

```
project.stories.all({ :story_type => ['feature'],  :includedone=>true }).sum(:estimate)
```

but this throws an error

```
undefined method `+' for #<PivotalTracker::Story:0x00000003aae9e0>
```

I then tried passing `estimate` as a filter parameter as well, but that returned with a internal server error.

Now, my problem lies where I had started from. Is there any way to achieve the above requirement? If not, please suggest any other gem which can provide a feature/functionality to achieve the above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but you can try with:

```
project.stories.all({ :story_type => ['feature'],  :includedone=>true }).map(&:estimate).sum
```